# How to get all entity kinds from GAE server?

Tags: google-app-engine, entity

How can I get all entity kinds from GAE server?
Is this possible?
I want to make a DB manager tool for GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to programmatically read the datastore stats. See the docs for doing so in [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/stats.html) or [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/stats.html). Here's a simple example in Python:

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext.db import stats
>>> kinds = stats.KindStat.all().fetch(1000)
>>> kind_names = [x.kind_name for x in kinds]
>>> kind_names
[u'A', u'AAFoo', u'AModel', u'ASDBD', u'Abc', u'Accumulator', u'Activity', # ...
```

You can test this for yourself in the [interactive console](http://shell.appspot.com/).

The datastore stats also provide piles of other details that will be useful in writing a datastore management tool. Good luck!

Comment: This stat doesn't reflect current status of DB, not suitable for original purpose of the question.

Comment: You didn't say anything about that in the question. Further, it's the only way - so if you're not happy with it, there's no alternative available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/metadataqueries). For example:

```
Query query = new Query(Entities.KIND_METADATA_KIND);
DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Iterable<Entity> entityIterable = datastoreService.prepare(query).asIterable();

for(Entity entity : entityIterable) {
    System.out.println("Entity kind: " + entity.getKey().getName());
}
```